# ADF V2 - SQL source dataset - column structure mapping issue

Tags: dataset, schema, azure-data-factory

In copy activity (SQL data set to azure blob), i'm using dynamic content for source data set, sink data set & Mapping of source and sink.

in SQL source i used SP output having 3 columns named (col1,col2,col3) in same order, but in source data set structure i used dynamic content with same name but different order (col2, col1, col3), because of that values are swapped between col1 & col2 in the source data set itself

My question is why name based mapping is not taking in ADF V2 data set.
in the same way for another Source (SP Output) returns 7 columns, if i want to use only 3 columns it picking first 3 columns only, there is no leverage of columns to choose using dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic schema mapping is really useful and saves a ton of work, specially when you dont have a fixed schema. In your case it seems that your schemas are always the same, so why not do the mapping yourself?

Just go to your copy activity, select the tab Mapping and click the button "New Mapping". It will pop 2 textbox with a line, indicating a column from source, being mapped to a column in the sink.

[image]

Just fill it with the corresponding names, and you should be good to go.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin for the reply, Actually My schema is different on each iteration, it works well when the SP output column order and Data set schema order same, i doubt why mapping by name is not working.

Comment: Then I guess you may be able to do it with dynamic content using ADF's built in functions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions.

Comment: Marin, yes it works well when dynamic content of source data set structure matches with SP output column order, actually i have lot of sp's need to modify the column order, its taking long time, i wonder why data set structure not mapped by name.